# Download to SD card or internal storage with DownloadManager

Tags: android, android-intent, apk, android-download-manager

I'm using `DownloadManager` to download an APK:

```
DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse("url"));
request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "app-debug.apk");
request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI);
enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE);
```

In the callback I'm then reading the downloaded file using `File file = context.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/app-debug.apk");`

On my phone I have internal storage and a SD card. Above file is always downloaded to interal storage. What I would like instead is to let the user choose if the file should be downloaded to interal storage or SD card.

How can I use `setDestinationInExternalFilesDir` to store the file either on SD card or on interal stroage? Second, how can I then properly retrieve the file in the callback?

Last but not least, I'm then installing the file using the following code:

```
File file = context.getApplicationContext().getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + "/app-debug.apk");

Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(file); //for Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= 24
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
    fileUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", file);
}
Intent promptInstall = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, fileUri);
promptInstall.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
promptInstall.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
promptInstall.setFlags( Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
promptInstall.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
context.startActivity(promptInstall);
```

An my path.xml looks as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="." /></paths>
```

If I'm downloading with DownloadManager either on SD card or internal storage, do I have to change `path.xml`?

Comment: setDestinationInExternalFilesDir() downloads to external files dir. And that does not reside on a removable sd card. Nor can it be used for that. It only expects a folder name. Not a full path.

Comment: Isnt there a different member with which you can set a full path?

Comment: You cannot use FileProvider to serve files on a removable micro sd card.

Comment: @blackapps So that means it is not possible with DownloadManager to download a file on sd card?

Comment: I dont know. I asked you if there is a member function where you can specify a full path. So its you that decides.

Comment: @blackapps Yes I have a full path available as File but how can I use it in DownloadManager?

Comment: My god.. that i asked you already twice. You should investigate. Then tell us the results.

Comment: @blackapps That I was asking in my question above because I don't know it.